# controller pass $scope value to another controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS, how can I pass input scope from first controller to the second controller for the data $scope.requestURL

I've search about the service method but I have no idea how to apply it.

```
    .controller('ZipController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.zipCode = '10028';

    $scope.setURL = function() {
    $scope.requestURL = 'http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?zip=' + $scope.zipCode + '&apikey=xxxxx';
    };

    }])

   .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', 
   function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get($scope.requestURL).success(function(data) {
   console.log(data.results);
   $scope.congress = data.results;
   });
   }]);
```

Comment: Say what you're trying to do without talking about code so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: Please just take the time to just learn how to use services.  They really help organize and encapsulate your code.  Maintainability and separation of concerns and all of that jazz.

Comment: Hello Steve, I just like to know how usually URL request are assemble from input field and go into &http request

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick solution: ..you don't have to use the $http core service for your case:

You can also read more about angular's constant service..

```
(function(angular) {
    var app = angular.module('myServiceModule', []);
    app.controller('ZipController', function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.zipCode = '10028';
        myService.setFunc($scope.zipCode);
        myService.zipCode = $scope.zipCode;
    });
    app.controller('ListController', function($scope, myService) {
        $scope.requestURL = myService.getFunc();
    });
    app.factory('myService', function() {
        var zipCode;
        var setFunc = function(zip) {
            zipCode = zip;
        };
        var getFunc = function() {
            return 'http://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?zip=' + zipCode + '&apikey=xxxxx'
        };
        return {
            zipCode: zipCode,
            setFunc: setFunc,
            getFunc: getFunc
        };
    });
})(window.angular);
```

Comment: thanks Pro... I will try this code... I'm a lil bit slow, your code should give me the insight.

Comment: you should accept it, if it is the right solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to $rootScope.requestURL and access it from the second controller.